# Let $a,b,c\geq 0$ and $a+b+c=3$

Tags: inequality

Prove that $$1+\left(\frac{3\sqrt{7}}{7}-1\right)\sqrt{abc}\leq\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+3(b+c)}}\leq\frac{3\sqrt{7}}{7}$$
I have done the right inequality in this way

**Solution of right inequality:** Let $\dfrac{a}{a+3b+3c}=\dfrac{x^2}{7}$, $\dfrac{b}{3a+b+3c}=\dfrac{y^2}{7}$ and $\dfrac{c}{3a+3b+c}=\dfrac{z^2}{7}$, where $x,y,z$ are positives.

Hence, we need to prove $x+y+z\leq 3$, where $$4x^2y^2z^2+8(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2)+7(x^2+y^2+z^2)=49$$Let $x+y+z>3$. $x=kp$, $y=kq$ and $z=kr$, where $p+q+r=3$ and $k>0$.

\begin{align*}
49 & =4x^2y^2z^2+8(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2)+7(x^2+y^2+z^2)\\
& =4k^6p^2q^2r^2+8k^4(p^2q^2+q^2r^2+r^2p^2)+7k^2(p^2+q^2+r^2)\\
& >4p^2q^2r^2+8(p^2q^2+q^2r^2+r^2p^2)+7(p^2+q^2+r^2)
\end{align*}which is contradiction because we'll prove now that $$4p^2q^2r^2+8(p^2q^2+q^2r^2+r^2p^2)+7(p^2+q^2+r^2)\geq 49$$Let $3u=p+q+r$, $3v^2=pq+qr+rp$ and $w^3=pqr$.

So we need to prove $f(w^3)\geq 0$, where $$f(w^3)=4w^6-48u^3w^3+14u^6-42u^4v^2+72u^2v^4$$ $f'(w^3)=8w^3-48u^3<0$, thus $f(w^3)$ is decreasing, which means enough to check when $w^3$ reaches maximum. Thus by $uvw$ theorem enough to check when $p=q$ and $r=3-2p$,$$2 (2 p - 1)^2 (p - 1)^2 (2 p^2 + 7)$$ which is true.

But i am unable to prove the left part.